# Using package name tags in post body text

Tags: discussion, tagging, markdown, formatting

I just got an answer of mine [edited](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/113727/revisions) so it now uses identifier formatting like `` `mdframed` `` (rendered “`mdframed`”) instead of tag names like `[tag:mdframed]` (rendered “[mdframed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mdframed)”). I can see how this would be more *correct* in the sense of what tags are supposed to do. On the other hand, I have the feeling that using tags in the way my original post used them *might* be useful nevertheless, since it would provide a pointer for people to click on where they could find a wiki, useful other questions and so on, without me having to research links. So I wonder, was this edit just a matter of personal taste, is this some established policy, or should we perhaps even encourage the use of tags in post text? I have no strong feelings either way, just being curious.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Policy from 'the early days' has been

- Package names are inserted as code
- If pointing to a package in an answer, it should if possible be linked to CTAN:

  ```
  [`some-package`](http://ctan.org/pkg/some-package)
  ```

Tags are used for tagging, which means that they are almost exclusively placed in the 'tags' part of a question and not in the main body. Sometimes tags make sense in comments ('There are lots of questions about `<tag>`'), or on meta (where the discussion may be about a tag rather than the package itself), but both cases are relatively rare.

Comment: Martin’s User Script comes in handy when linking to CTAN or `texdoc.net`: [User script for CTAN Package and TeXDoc.net buttons](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2467)